# Assign a Server CPU core to execute a specific call

Tags: linux, soap, process, cpu, sybase

Is there a way in which I can prioritize a specific call to be executed by a CPU core?

meaning, if this call is passed, a CPU core will be then dedicated to execute that call.

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. What sort of call - database query, OS, web? As it stands you've added multiple tags with no details at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, system calls that are invoked by interrupts can be associated with cores using the IRQ mapping facility.  A high-level explanation is at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/s-cpu-irq

If you are writing your own device driver, then the Linux kernel provides easy interfaces to run a function on a specific core.  The kernel function "smp_call_function_single()" is an example -- there are others in kernel/smp.c, and there are plenty of examples of the use of these functions in other bits of kernel code -- e.g., arch/x86/lib/msr-smp.c and arch/x86/kernel/cpuid.c are where I learned about these functions.

My experience with kernel code is quite limited, but I don't know of any mechanism to provide differential affinity control of the execution of functions that are accessed using the same interrupt number/IRQ.  Depending on the complexity of the function, it may be possible to create a simple driver that wraps the desired call in "smp_call_function_single()".